# ECS cdk blue green deployment

Tags: aws-cdk

I am looking to do a blue green deployment via aws-cdk, I am in exploring phase of cdk and I am not sure how to handle blue green deployments via cdk.
request you to provide the details regarding the blue green deployment in cdk.

Answer (score -1):

Here are some relevant links regarding blue-green deployments on EKS in AWS, hope this helps you:

- https://cicd-pipeline-cdk-eks-bluegreen.workshop.aws/en/ecsbg.html
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/create-a-pipeline-with-canary-deployments-for-amazon-eks-with-aws-app-mesh/

Comment: I was looking for cdk approach, this looks like a aws console approach :(